# Writing a 3D array from Petsc

Tags: matrix, petsc

I am trying to do something fairly simple somehow I have made it hard.
Is there an example of how to send a 3D array to a binary file?

Comment: Is your "3D array" actually a distributed Vec based on a DMDA?  If so, you should use `VecView` like Geoff says.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the object representation of your 3D array. If it's a PETSc `Mat`, you want to look at [`MatView`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatView.html); if it's a `Vec`, you want to look at [`VecView`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Vec/VecView.html). The links are to PETSc documentation, and each of the links has a list of relevant examples. They may not be exactly what you're looking for, but they should be close; in general, you're looking for something like a "View" type command. If these suggestions don't help, I suggest e-mailing the PETSc user list.